# Issue loading data set using spark-redis

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, redis, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a data set with spark-redis, but the operation always fail. The spark dataframe that I am trying to write has 85 million rows, but the write operation roughly fails after 25 million rows in. I wonder how to solve this kind of problem.

Here are the operations that I execute in my Python script:

```
    SPARK_JARS = ['/home/jovyan/jedis-3.6.0.jar', '/home/jovyan/spark-redis_2.12-2.6.0.jar']

    spark = (SparkSession.builder.master(master_uri).appName('redis.test')
                         .config('spark.executor.memory', '28g')
                         .config('spark.cores.max', 16)
                         .config('spark.redis.host', REDIS_HOST)
                         .config('spark.redis.port', 6379)
                         .config('spark.redis.db', 0)
                         .config('spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields', 65535)
                         .config('spark.jars', ','.join(SPARK_JARS)).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate())

    df = spark.sql('select * from input_table')

    df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "output_table").option("key.column", "id").option("dbNum", 0).save();
```

I am trying to store information from an Iceberg table to a Redis hash. The version of spark-redis I am using is spark-redis_2.12-2.6.0.jar. I am running my script on Spark 3.1.1 and the Redis cluster I am trying to access uses version 6.0.4. When I run the script, it starts loading the data in the hash from for a couple of minutes. Then, a SocketTimeoutException is raised. But the data continues to be loaded in the hash. However, after 10 minutes (this varies from session to session), there is an additional failure and from this point, I cannot connect to the Redis data store anymore (connection refused). This connection refusal state is temporary, but can last a few hours.

Here is the log (I had to skip parts of it because it was too long to fit in a message):

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.8 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.8 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.8 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.8 used for parser compilation does not match 21/06/07 17:26:08 WARN SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
21/06/07 17:30:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 16) (x.x.x.x executor 0): redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:205)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:43)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:158)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:223)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:352)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getMany(Connection.java:364)
at redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline.sync(Pipeline.java:98)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.util.PipelineUtils$.$anonfun$foreachWithPipeline$1(PipelineUtils.scala:71)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.util.PipelineUtils$.$anonfun$foreachWithPipeline$1$adapted(PipelineUtils.scala:67)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.util.PipelineUtils$.foreachWithPipeline(PipelineUtils.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$8(RedisSourceRelation.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$8$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:141)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$6(RedisSourceRelation.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$6$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:138)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$5(RedisSourceRelation.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$5$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2242)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
… 35 more

21/06/07 17:41:57 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 19.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 22) (x.x.x.x executor 0): redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:205)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:43)
…
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
… 35 more

21/06/07 17:52:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.2 in stage 2.0 (TID 42) (x.x.x.x executor 0): redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unexpected end of stream.
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:43)
…
21/06/07 17:52:54 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 46) (x.x.x.x executor 0): redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:205)
…
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
… 35 more

21/06/07 17:52:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 52) (x.x.x.x executor 0): redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:84)
…
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to create socket.
at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:110)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:226)
…
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:80)
… 38 more

21/06/07 17:52:56 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 4 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “redis_load.py”, line 106, in
df = spark.sql(‘select * from input_table’)
File “/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py”, line 1107, in save
self._jwrite.save()
File “/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py”, line 1304, in call
return_value = get_return_value(
File “/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py”, line 111, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File “/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py”, line 326, in get_return_value
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 52) (x.x.x.x executor 0): redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:84)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:366)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.ConnectionPool$.connect(ConnectionPool.scala:35)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisEndpoint.connect(RedisConfig.scala:72)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisNode.connect(RedisConfig.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$8(RedisSourceRelation.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$8$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:141)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$6(RedisSourceRelation.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$6$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:138)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$5(RedisSourceRelation.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$5$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2242)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to create socket.
at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:110)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:226)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:135)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:309)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.initializeFromClientConfig(BinaryJedis.java:87)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.(BinaryJedis.java:292)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.(Jedis.java:167)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:177)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:75)
… 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:80)
… 38 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2253)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2202)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2382)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2371)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2202)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2223)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2242)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2267)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:1018)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$foreachPartition$1(Dataset.scala:2906)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1(Dataset.scala:3676)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3674)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2906)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.insert(RedisSourceRelation.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:30)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:301)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:84)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:366)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.ConnectionPool$.connect(ConnectionPool.scala:35)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisEndpoint.connect(RedisConfig.scala:72)
at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisNode.connect(RedisConfig.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$8(RedisSourceRelation.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$8$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:141)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$6(RedisSourceRelation.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$6$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:138)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$5(RedisSourceRelation.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.$anonfun$insert$5$adapted(RedisSourceRelation.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2242)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
… 1 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed to create socket.
at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:110)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:226)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:135)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:309)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.initializeFromClientConfig(BinaryJedis.java:87)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.(BinaryJedis.java:292)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.(Jedis.java:167)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:177)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:75)
… 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at redis.clients.jedis.DefaultJedisSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultJedisSocketFactory.java:80)
… 38 more

21/06/07 17:52:57 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 15.2 in stage 2.0 (TID 67) (x.x.x.x executor 0): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
```

It looks like there is some connection pool that gets exhausted, but I have no idea how you can tell spark-redis how connections should be allocated and when to recycle them. I also do not know if the problem arise because of the network configuration or maybe the Redis server configuration. Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this problems would be appreciated.

I am also getting similar problems when I run python script of Java app that uses the Redis API to read and write to Redis using pipelines.

Comment: Do you see any issues in redis logs?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing many of these logs:
Asynchronous AOF fsync is taking too long (disk is busy?)

It looks like while performing the write, because I have enabled persistence in my Redis server, the server is periodically writing the hash to disk which causes a delay in response from time to time. The socket (read) timeout is 2 seconds by default I believe. It seems like the sevrer may not respond within this limit at times. I have increased this to a much higher value doing .config("spark.redis.timeout", DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) on the Spark context (I could have also set the timeout on the dataframe adding the following option to the write operation: .option("timeout", DEFAULT_TIMEOUT).